# Control padding programmatically in Clojure format (java.util.Formatter), cl-format (Common Lisp format)?

Tags: java, clojure, common-lisp, string-formatting

Is there a way to use Clojure `forrmat` (based on `java.util.Formatter`) or `cl-format` (based on Common Lisp's `format`) to set space padding programmatically?  If you know the desired width in advance these both return `"   foo"`:

```
(format "%6s" "foo")
(clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~6d" "foo")
```

But what if I want the program to decide how wide the returned string should be?  Obviously I can construct the format string by hand, e.g.:

```
(def width 6)
(format (str "%" width "s") "foo")
```

But I thought I remembered that there was a Common Lisp `format` directive that could simply insert the value of a format argument into a format directive, and then use the resulting constructed directive to process the next argument.  However, I haven't yet found such a directive in the [CL Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/) or [CLTL2](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node200.html#SECTION002633000000000000000) (which doesn't mean that the information is not there).  Nor have I discovered such a directive in the `java.util.Formatter` documentation, so far.  Is there a way to control directives with directives in any of these formatting functions/classes?

(I'm not sure whether my `cl-format` example is supposed to work, since `d` is a number-formatting directive.  It does work in Clojure 1.5.1.  The same trick works in CLISP with `format`, but not in SBCL, ABCL, CCL, or ECL.)

Edit:
(I've discovered that the correct way to left-pad a string is by adding `@` to the `a` directive, rather than by using `d`:

```
(clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~6@a" "foo")
```

This method should always work in Common Lisp, and by using `@a` rather than `d` in Clojure, one avoids the risk that a future implementation of `cl-format` will change the behavior of `d` with strings, which is an unintended use.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Common Lisp, you can use `v` as a prefix parameter, e.g.:

```
(format nil "~vd" 10 42)
```

It's documented here: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_c.htm

> In place of a prefix parameter to a directive, V (or v) can be used. In this case, format takes an argument from args as a parameter to the directive.

Comment: Excellent.  That's just what I was looking for.  I had not noticed the paragraph on "v" on that page of the Hyperspec.  The same method works with Clojure's `cl-format`.